# Norm of projection on non-orthonormal basis using scalar products only

Tags: orthonormal, projection

Let's say I have an $N$-dimensional space and some subspace with a non-orthonormal unitary basis , defined by vectors : $$ \vec{Ss}  : (\vec{u_1}, \vec{u_2}, \cdots, \vec{u_{n}})$$
All I know about my vectors is their scalar products with each other.

Now, let's say I have some unitary vector $ \vec{v}$, and I want to know the norm of its projection on $ \vec{Ss}$. Same thing, all I know about $ \vec{v}$ is its scalar products with $ \vec{Ss}$ vectors.

I'm thinking of a recursive algorithm to perform this (recursive regarding the subspace dimension $n$), but it doesn't work, I must have made some mistake. Here's my R code :

```
myFunction_orthogonalize <- function(subScalars) 
{
  # subScalars : square matrix of subspace scalar products

  if(is.null(ncol(subScalars))) # subspace dimension is 1
  {
    return(1)
  }
  else
  {
    thisDimensions <- nrow(subScalars)
    previousSubspaceExpression <- myFunction_projection(subScalars[-thisDimensions,-thisDimensions])

    thisNewVect_withoutLastScalar <- t(previousSubspaceExpression)%*%(subScalars[,thisDimensions][-thisDimensions] %>% matrix(nrow = thisDimensions-1, ncol = 1)
    daNorm <- sqrt(1-sum(thisNewVect_withoutLastScalar^2))

    beforsLast <- c(rep(0,thisDimensions-1),1) - c(thisNewVect_withoutLastScalar, 0)
    return(cbind(rbind(previousSubspaceExpression, c(rep(0,thisDimensions-1))) , (beforsLast/daNorm)))
  }
}

myFunction_norm <- function(subScalars, toProject_scalars) 
{
  # subScalars : square matrix of subspace scalar products
  # toProject_scalars : vector of scalar products of the vector to project and subspace vectors
  return(norm(t(myFunction_orthogonalize(subScalars))%*%rndmVector_scalars, type = '2'))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you need a recursive algorithm because you have to work with too large dimensions? Or you might be able to invert an $n\times n$ symmetric  matrix (or Hermitian, if working in $\mathbb C$) without too much rounding error and in reasonable time scales?

In that case, you can see that the norm of the projection $\vec v\,'$ of $\vec v\in \mathbb V$ over the $n$-dimensional subspace $S\subseteq \mathbb V$ can be obtained from

> $$\|\,\vec v\,'\|^2=\vec \beta \cdot M^{-1} \cdot \vec \beta\,^T,$$

where $$\vec \beta=\big(\begin{matrix}\langle \vec v,\vec u_1\rangle&\langle \vec v,\vec u_2\rangle &\ldots &\langle \vec v,\vec u_n\rangle\\\end{matrix}\big)$$
and
$$M=\left(\begin{matrix}\langle \vec u_1,\vec u_1\rangle&\langle \vec u_1,\vec u_2\rangle&\cdots&\langle \vec u_1,\vec u_n\rangle\\\langle\vec u_2,\vec u_1\rangle&\langle \vec u_2,\vec u_2\rangle&\cdots&\langle \vec u_2,\vec u_n\rangle\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\\langle\vec u_n,\vec u_1\rangle&\langle \vec u_n,\vec u_2\rangle&\cdots&\langle \vec u_n,\vec u_n\rangle\\\end{matrix}\right)$$
(assuming that the scalars are real numbers; if not, the transpose needs to be changed to the conjugate-transpose and $M$ is not symmetrical but Hermitian).

---

---

*Proof:* (For the real case.) Since $\vec v\,'$ is actually in $S$, you can say that
$$\vec v\,'=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \vec u_i$$
(all sums in the following go from $1$ to $n$) for some scalars $\alpha_i$ $(*)$. Let's put them all together in a row vector
$$\vec\alpha=\big(\begin{matrix}\alpha_1&\alpha_2&\ldots&\alpha_n\\\end{matrix}\big).$$

Also, since $\vec v-\vec v\,'$ lies in the orthogonal space of $S$ and $\vec u_i\in S$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$, it is true for all $i$ that $\langle \vec v-\vec v\,',\vec u_i\rangle=0$, that is
$$\langle \vec v,\vec u_i\rangle=\langle \vec v\,',\vec u_i\rangle.$$

Now, we see that
$$\beta_j=\langle \vec v,\vec u_j\rangle=\langle \vec v\,',\vec u_j\rangle=\left\langle \sum_i \alpha_i \vec u_i,\vec u_j\right\rangle=\sum_i \alpha_i \langle\vec u_i,\vec u_j\rangle=\sum_i \alpha_i M_{ij}=\big(\vec\alpha\cdot M\big)_j.$$
In matrix notation:
$$\vec\alpha \cdot M=\vec \beta,$$
and so
$$\vec\alpha =\vec \beta \cdot M^{-1}.$$
But we need $\|\vec v\,'\|=\sqrt{\langle \vec v\,',\vec v\,'\rangle}$. Now,
$$\langle \vec v\,',\vec v\,'\rangle=\left\langle\sum_i \alpha_i \vec u_i,\sum_j \alpha_j \vec u_j\right\rangle=\sum_i \sum_j \alpha_i \langle \vec u_i,\vec u_j \rangle \alpha_j=\sum_i \alpha_i \left(\sum_j M_{ij} \alpha_j\right)=$$
$$=\sum_i \alpha_i \big(M\cdot \vec \alpha\,^T\big)_i=\vec \alpha\cdot M\cdot \vec \alpha\,^T.$$

And finally, since $\vec \alpha=\vec \beta\cdot M^{-1}$ and $M^T=M$, we have
$$\|\vec v\,'\|^2=\vec \beta\cdot M^{-1}\cdot M \cdot \left(\vec \beta\cdot M^{-1}\right)^T=\vec \beta \cdot M^{-1} \cdot\vec \beta\,^T,$$
as desired.

$(*)$ Actually, this is true always if $S$ is generated by the vectors $\vec u_1,\ldots,\vec u_n$; but if $\big(\vec u_1,\ldots,\vec u_n\big)$ is linearly independent—that is, a base of $S$—, the $\alpha_i$ scalars are uniquely determined. Moreover, this assumption is fundamental in order that the matrix $M$ that we will define be invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which does the job. In my sense, the big advantage of your method is its non-recursivity. That being said, there is a problem with something I didn't mention : the precision of the computations is extremely important in my case. Actually, I am using a multiple precision floating-point package for that purpose. It is called Rmpfr. Unfortunately, it doesn't implement matrix inversion... I will have to implement by my self to use your method.

Comment: I'm glad it helps. There are some methods that could work fine in this case: to mention one which is well-known, being the matrix to invert a symmetric/Hermitian and positive definite matrix (as it is the case with any inner product matrix), Cholesky decomposition could do the job.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#/Matrix_inversion

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there were some mistakes in the algorithm, here is one that works fine :

```
myFunction_orthogonalize <- function(subScalars)
{
  # subScalars : square matrix of subspace scalar products

  if(is.null(ncol(subScalars)))
  {
    return(1)
  }
  else
  {
    thisDimensions <- nrow(subScalars)
    previousSubspaceExpression <- myFunction_orthogonalize(subScalars[-thisDimensions,-thisDimensions])
    thisNewVect_withoutLast <- (previousSubspaceExpression%*%t(previousSubspaceExpression))%*%(subScalars[1:(thisDimensions-1),thisDimensions])
    daNorm <- sqrt(1-sum((t(previousSubspaceExpression)%*%(subScalars[1:(thisDimensions-1),thisDimensions]))^2))
    beforsLast <- c(rep(0,thisDimensions-1),1) - c(thisNewVect_withoutLast, 0)
    return(cbind(rbind(previousSubspaceExpression, c(rep(0,thisDimensions-1))) , (beforsLast/daNorm)))
  }
}

myFunction_norm <- function(subScalars, toProject_scalars) 
{
  # subScalars : square matrix of subspace scalar products
  # toProject_scalars : vector of scalar products of the vector to project and subspace vectors

  return(norm(t(myFunction_orthogonalize(subScalars))%*%toProject_scalars, type = '2'))
}
```